# Can you apprehend something instead of someone?

Tags: word-usage

Can the verb "apprehend" used to mean "to check"?

I'm asking this because because I came across this sentence in my book:

> **Apprehending** social and communal disharmony, the government banned Rashtriya Swayamsevak Sangh RSS and Jamait-e-Islami.

I think the author is trying to convey the sense of "check" through "apprehend"? Am I right? Because I didn't find any dictionary describing this usage of the verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[apprehend](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/apprehend)** (v):
>   1. Arrest (someone) for a crime.
>   2. Understand or perceive.

As with any "educated" vocabulary (in any language), using "apprehend" instead of "understand" in casual conversation may be considered *erudite* by some, but *pretentious* by others.   You have to know your audience, and where it sounds appropriate.  However it's not uncommon to see it written in articles, literature, essays, academic journals, and similar media.

That being said, I personally think this use in the example in your book is awkward.  While "apprehend" can mean "perceive", the government isn't just *noticing* the social disharmony.  It would be more natural to say that the government is *expecting* and *avoiding* social disharmony by preemptively banning these two, e.g.:

> **Anticipating** social and communal disharmony, the government banned ...

or, alternately, that they are *defusing* the situation by banning the people they consider responsible:

> **Responding to** social and communal disharmony, the government banned ...

There are many other ways to describe the situation, but I would be unlikely to use "apprehending" to do so.

Side note:  "Comprehend" is a synonym for "understand" that (as Nic Hartley says) is *slightly* more educated but still very common.  Again, it's not a word I would use in this context, but it's a lot less fancy than "apprehend".

Comment: I'd add a note about "**com**prehend", which is still fancier than "understand", but also more likely to be understood than "**ap**prehend."

Comment: look at sense 2.1 under that lexico definition.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  marked as "archaic".  18th century English is not appropriate in a 21st century textbook.

Comment: As you will see from my answer, several other dictionaries do not label this sense as "archaic", nor do I agree with such a label. Indeed I have used this sense in my own writing. Even if this is thought "old-fashioned" it was common in the early 20 th century if not later.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  fair enough.  If you would use it, then it's reasonable for this textbook to do the same.  It seems odd to me, but I'll admit it's personal preference.

Comment: FYI Google Ngram shows that the use of "apprehend" as a verb became less common than "anticipate" (also as a verb) shortly after 1900. Previously it was significantly more common. However, this does not distinguish between the various senses of the verb, so its relevance is uncertain.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I'd say "Apprehend" (sense 2) has a connotation of time. It's not _just_ understanding; it's more "I have _just understood_." It's intellectual grasping. Like, you captured ("apprehended") the meaning as it was trying to escape from you, and now you have it. So it's not a strict synonym IMO.¶ Note that this also makes the OP's sentence more-coherent: "apprehend" translates something like: "Coming to understand the impact of", whereas simple "understanding" is not as precise nor accurate.

Answer (score 3):

The usual meaning of "apprehend" is "understand or perceive". (dictionary link)

So I would interpret the sentence to mean "Understanding (how they could cause) social disharmony ..."

It doesn't mean "check", it means "get hold of" either physically or mentally.

Answer (score 1):

A third meanign of "apprehend", as [listed at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apprehend), at [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/apprehend), at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apprehend), at [The free dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/apprehend), and at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/apprehend) is

> to expect with anxiety, suspicion, or fear; anticipate:
>
> > *apprehending violence.*

The free dictionary and Lexico list this sense as "archaic", the others do not, and I don't think it is at all archaic. This sense is connected with 'apprehensive" = fearful. Some dictionaries do not give this sense at all.

It is exactly this sense that is being used here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the author is using the word "apprehending" to mean "being apprehensive of".  Although "apprehending" and "apprehensive" are obviously related, I'm certain that the vast majority of fluent English speakers would consider this particular usage to be incorrect or at least unfamiliar, although it has been identified as an "archaic" usage in this related answer [Can you apprehend something instead of someone?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215531/can-you-apprehend-something-instead-of-someone/215598#215598) .

At the very least, one can say that this usage is so rare that other meanings of "apprehending" come to mind first and tend to confuse the reader.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the correct and accepted answer pointing out the other meaning of **apprehend** (*to understand or perceive*), I am here to answer just the short version of the question: "Can you apprehend something instead of someone?" using **just the first definition**, as in the sense of being arrested for an alleged crime.

**The answer is still yes**, at least in some places.

As advice for a writer, I would tend to recommend "seizure" as a more accurate way to describe the practice.  In the US (see John Oliver's introduction [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kEpZWGgJks)), officials usually use the term "forfeiture" to [usually successfully] try to get around the [4th Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/fourth_amendment)'s restrictions.  "Apprehend" is reasonably used when trying to imply any willingness in giving up (as "forfeit*" does) would be clearly counterproductive, yet "seizure" still needs to be avoided.

Comment: While Civil Forfeiture is indeed an often unjust procedure, it is not just a matter of terminology, and the legal consequences do **not** depend on the term used, although they cna depend on the legal route taken.  Nor is it accurate to speak of apprehending or arresting things in a forfeiture case -- that is pure hyperbole. Regardless of that, this is in no way an answer to the original question.

Comment: A "go fast" boat used in drug smuggling operations was "apprehended" as noted on p. 19 of a [US treasury report on civil asset forfeiture](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/terrorist-illicit-finance/Asset-Forfeiture/Documents/04-annual-report.pdf).  If some potential OP is seeing the word "apprehend" used for goods being seized, I would say it's a reasonable word choice given the constraints. And yes, no matter how ideal you'd like to think courts are, specific choice of words *does* matter on the scales of persuasion.